# What was the minimum age to receive the death penalty?

Tags: halacha, capital-punishment, age

When it was a possibility, what was the minimum age to receive the death penalty? Was it 13?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/capital-crimes-committed-by-minors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Midrash [(Bamidbar Rabbah 18:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.18.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that instead of the Heavenly Court, the Court Below can impose such a penalty from thirteen years old:

> An emissary of the court on high only imposes a penalty [on people] from the age of twenty years, **while the court below [only imposes a penalty] from the age of thirteen years.** (emphasis mine)

Rashi, in his commentary to [Numbers 16:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.27?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.16.27.2&lang2=bi) explains that the Court Below does not punish a person before he shows signs of puberty. Thirteen years old is the age in which the Torah considers a person to be a man and not a child anymore [(see Avos 5:21 with the commentary of the Bartenura)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.5.21.3&lang2=bi)

See also [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/esrim-mi-yodeya/1110#comment381455_1110) on a earlier post.